# finding an ID name of a class when using an event listener

Tags: javascript, event-handling

lets say I have 2 vertical buttons on the left hand side:

```
<div class="button" id="files" >files</div>
<div class="button" id="dirs">dirs</div>
```

when one is clicked I want it to put its corresponding box next to it (inline)

```
<div class="commands_group" id="files_commands">file commands</div>
<div class="commands_group" id="dirs_commands">dir commands</div>
```

I've started off by adding an event listener to each button:

```
window.onload = init;

function init()
{
    'use strict';
    var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

    for(var i=0;i<classname.length;i++)
    {
        classname[i].addEventListener('click', show_commands(), false);
    }
}
```

which is fine. But now I want to put the corresponding box inline i.e. if the files button was clicked files_commands needs to go from display:none to display: inline.

I'm having trouble selecting the corresponding box

my current code is:

```
function show_commands()
{   
    'use strict';

    var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("commands_group");
    for(var i=0;i<classname.length;i++)
    {       
        classname[i].style.display = 'none';    
    } //just to reset the view to nothing
```

the below should be the main part **(and is the basis of my question)** but I don't know how to select the specific id of the commands group

```
    var name = this.id.stringValue.concat("_commands");
    document.getElementById(name).style.display = 'inline';

}
```

Comment: `addEventListener('click', show_commands(), false);` should be `addEventListener('click', show_commands, false);`

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it still doesn't seem to like it

Comment: To be fair, this answer and the marked one were both required. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this you wanted?

```
var name = this.id.stringValue.concat("_commands");
```

this line should be  `var name = this.id.concat("_commands");`

```js
window.onload = init;

function init()
{
    'use strict';
    var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

    for(var i=0;i<classname.length;i++)
    {
        classname[i].addEventListener('click', show_commands, false);
    }
}

function show_commands()
{   
    'use strict';

    var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("commands_group");
    for(var i=0;i<classname.length;i++)
    {       
        classname[i].style.display = 'none';    
    } //just to reset the view to nothing

    var name = this.id.concat("_commands");
    document.getElementById(name).style.display = 'inline';

}
```

```html
<div class="button" id="files" >files</div>
<div class="button" id="dirs">dirs</div>    

<div class="commands_group" id="files_commands">file commands</div>
<div class="commands_group" id="dirs_commands">dir commands</div>
```